# Nodemailer is sending out blank emails when no post request was submitted to the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest, nodemailer

I created a simple Node web application that displays a home page and contains a "contact me" form. The application parses the info that the user enters into the form and uses Nodemailer to then generate an email from my Zoho account and email me the info (as well as send a confirmation email to the email address the user provided). The desired functionality works as planned, however, there is some kind of bug whereby a blank email is fired off roughly every half hour or so and I cannot figure out why.

[image: image of blank email arriving]

There is validation on the page that doesn't allow the user to submit with any of the inputs left blank and I also tried adding a line of code to the server.js file to only execute .sendMail() if the content was not blank and it still does not stop the blank emails from coming.

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: \__dirname + '/.env' });
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) =\> {
res.sendFile(\__dirname + '/public/views/index.html');
});

app.post('/', (req, res) =\> {

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: 'smtp.zoho.com',
port: 465,
secure: true,
auth: {
user: process.env.ZOHO_USERNAME,
pass: process.env.ZOHO_PASS,
},
});

const mailOptions = {
from: process.env.ZOHO_GREG,
to: process.env.MY_EMAIL,
subject: `Message from: ${req.body.name} <${req.body.email}> : ${req.body.subject}`,
text: req.body.message,
};

const confirmationOptions = {
from: process.env.ZOHO_NO_REPLY,
to: req.body.email,
subject: `Message Receipt Confirmation`,
text: "I received the message that you sent through my website. Thank you, I'll be in touch.",
};

if (req.body.name !== undefined) {
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) =\> {
if (err) {
console.log(err);
res.send('error');
} else {
res.send('success');
console.log('successfully sent email');
}
});

transporter.sendMail(confirmationOptions, (err, info) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.send('error');
  } else {
    res.send('success');
    console.log('successfully sent email');
  }
});

}
```

});

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}.`);
});

// Front end script snippet

```
contactForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) =\> {
e.preventDefault();

if (validate() === false) {
return;
}

let formData = {
name: senderName.value,
email: senderEmail.value,
subject: senderSubject.value,
message: senderMessage.value,
};

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
xhr.onload = function () {
if (xhr.responseText === 'success') {
if (sentMessages === 0) {
document.querySelector('.success').innerHTML =
"<h2 class='message-sent'>Thank you, I've received your message.</h1>";
} else if (sentMessages === 1) {
document.querySelector('.success').innerHTML =
"<h2 class='message-sent'>Thank you. I've received your message, again. </h1>";
} else {
document.querySelector('.success').innerHTML =
"<h2 class='message-sent'>Three is the limit, please try again later </h1>";
senderName.disabled = true;
senderEmail.disabled = true;
senderSubject.disabled = true;
senderMessage.disabled = true;
submitButton.disabled = true;
submitButton.classList.add('disable-btn');
}
senderName.value = '';
senderEmail.value = '';
senderSubject.value = '';
senderMessage.value = '';

  sentMessages++;
} else {
  if (errorMessages === 0) {
    document.querySelector('.success').innerHTML =
      "<h2 class='message-sent'>Uh, oh. Something went wrong.......</h1>";
    errorMessages++;
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.success').innerHTML =
      "<h2 class='message-sent'>There must be an issue, please try again later.</h1>";
  }
  senderName.value = '';
  senderEmail.value = '';
  senderSubject.value = '';
  senderMessage.value = '';
}

};
```

xhr.send(JSON.stringify(formData));
});